# Required table missing : "DBS" in Catalog "" Schema ""

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to run Hive on my Windows machine.
But when i am trying to run the command from **C:\hadoop-2.7.1\hive-2.1.0\bin>hive** it gives the following Error.

```
Required table missing : "DBS" in Catalog "" Schema "". 
DataNucleus requires this table to perform its persistence operations. 
Either your MetaData is incorrect, or you need to enable "datanucleus.schema.autoCreateTables"
org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.exceptions.MissingTableException: Required table missing : "DBS" in Catalog "" Schema "".
DataNucleus requires this table to perform its persistence operations.
Either your MetaData is incorrect, or you need to enable "datanucleus.schema.autoCreateTables"
    at    org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.AbstractTable.exists(AbstractTable.java:606)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the hive schema .sql scripts mentioned in **$HIVE_HOME\scripts\metastore\upgrade\mysql**. In my case, I am using **mysql** as the underlying db for **hive 2.1.1** so I ran hive-schema-2.1.0.mysql.sql.
You can try as per your DB.

Comment: where did you run this? I am using derby.

Comment: I used it while i was configuring single node cluster on windows machine and used mysql for metastore.